# Horizontal Staggered Gridlayout Recyclerview and volley issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Screenshot urls:
http://postimg.org/gallery/pkgkwkuo/

As seen in the screenshot, the upper row continues to fill but the lower row contains only one item.

When orientation is changed then it sorts correctly

The blank card is due to less internet speed, proceeding images are loaded.

What is the issue? Here is the code

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);
        listView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
        listView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), listView, this));
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        responseGot = response;
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Gallery movie = new Gallery(obj.getString("title"),obj.getString("image"),obj.getInt("year"));

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.setList(movieList);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
```